# Sms going to email

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4-mini

I read up on how to stop this but the sync sms box was already unchecked but my sms keep going to my email. However only some of my messages come thru to me as an sms. There are some that have been sent to me by sms but I can only get them via my email... SOMEONE HELP PLZ

Answer (score 0):

You need to turn off SMS Sync in your Exchange Account settings.

Click on the Exchange ActiveSync account and then select settings. Scroll down to the bottom and then click on More Settings. On this screen you'll see an option to Sync SMS. Make sure this is unchecked, that should take care of it.

BTW, this is a simple Google search away...

Comment: As I said I've done all that and it's still happening.. When I went into the 'more settings' sms sync was already unchecked...